# How to overlay control on top of a row in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a requirement to add a specific control on top of rows that contain data that matches specific criteria. Those criteria are missing required information that needs to be added with an inline editing feature. What we want is a navigation control that seats on top of the first matching row and that leads you to the next one by clicking on "next", which will make the grid scroll up to the next matching row which will display another control on top and above allowing to navigate to next matching row or go to previous.

So let's say we have a list of cars, and we want the user to navigate over the rows of cars that have a price lower or equals to 45k, you'll see something like:

[image]

On the next click you'll see something like:

[image]

I believe in order to have this feature, I would need a reference to the rows and inject a component in the DOM relative to each row on click. But I'm not sure how to do that. I've attempted to dynamically add the component to the native element of the first matching row like this:

```
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.api = params.api;
    this.columnApi = params.columnApi;

    params.api.forEachNode((node, index) => {
      if(node.data.price <= 45000) {
        this.matchingIndexes.push(index);
      }
    });

    let firstRowRef = this.gridElementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(`[row-index="${this.matchingIndexes[0]}"]`)[1];
    
    const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PagingOverlayComponent)
    const component = factory.create(firstRowRef.parentInjector)
    this.viewContainerRef.insert(component.hostView);
  }
```

I want to be able to insert the component somehow in relation to the row it has to be attached so I can position it over it. This is the farthest I have been able to go:

[image]

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

[Please find a working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-control-overlay-on-top-of-row?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: You need to attach the element to the document body - that should work hopefully. An alternative solution would be to leverage a custom cell renderer component to create the control inside the cell, this is more easier to achieve: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/component-cell-renderer/

Answer (score 3):

We did something fairly similar to this for an application in our bank, but we are using AdapTable which is a component that sits on top of ag-Grid.

That has a search function which includes an option just to return all result sets.  It also has api methods to jump to a cell and highlight a cell.  So we created something very similar to this and each time you clicked the arrow we got AdapTable to highlight and jump to the relevant cell in ag-Grid.

It was quite easy to implement - a couple of hours at most - but as I say we used AdapTable and not ag-Grid directly and I don't know what that does internally to return the search result set to us.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use native element to achieve this.

Try a combination of:

1. An AgGrid Cell Renderer for the Pagination Control, and
2. A shared service to manage the pagination/search logic. It will need to answer questions (from each Cell Renderer instance) such as 'does this row index match?', 'which number match am I?' and 'how many matches are there in total?'

I [forked your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-control-overlay-on-top-of-row-eeyzbv?embed=1&file=src/app/paging-overlay/paging-overlay.component.ts) to get you started. The paginator resides in the `make` column - matches show the paginator, non-matches show the make. You'll still need to implement logic to:

- hide the paginator based on which row is selected.
- scroll to next/previous

Comment: Thanks for the work there. What I really want is to "combine" to an existing column as you've said. The final look should be something like the screenshots on my question, that is, to appear like an overlay control on top of the matching row that will go away on "next" click to appear on top of the next matching row. An AgGrid Cell Renderer sounds promising, still need to figure this out (working on other things right now)

Comment: No worries. Move the cell renderer to the column you want to combine it with, and then then show / hide the pagination based on whether the row is selected (`api.getSelectedNodes()`). Add buttons for selecting next / previous matched RowNode (using `RowNode.setSelected(true)`) and presumably scroll to the selected one (using `api.ensureIndexVisible`) and you're pretty much there.